# How to install and run (setup) reddit.com on windows environment?

Tags: windows, reddit

Reddit.com is providing their code as open source and free.

I want to setup the reddit.com website at my local machine in Windows Environment.

Could anybody please help me or guide me to the best approach.

Also, i have apache (WAMP) installed in my machine.

Kindly somebody help, I have searched everywhere but unable to find the way to setup it in my local environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Reddit](http://blog.reddit.com/2008/06/reddit-goes-open-source.html) blog it is built and runs upon:
Debian, lighttpd, PostgreSQL, Python ...

None of them is an acronym of WAMP.

A good place to start would be:
http://code.reddit.com/

I recommend setting up a [Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/) with Debian linux and work within it.